# RegEx Replace Matching Sequence and Stripping Whitespaces

Tags: c#, php, javascript, regex, asp-classic

I have some string entries that look like this:

```
00 34 32 35 00 33 00 47 : A Cat
77 59 32 35 00 00 00 11 : Dog
29 59 32 35 01 00 00 11 : Dog's Toy
```

I have to transform them as following using a RegEx replace:

```
<Entry Name="A Cat" Code="0034323500330047"/>
<Entry Name="Dog" Code="7759323500000011"/>
<Entry Name="Dog's Toy" Code="2959323501000011"/>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why all those tags ? What language do you want to use ?

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Also, I doubt you're using all four languages for this. Which one are you *actually using*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex to make the transformation isn't the simplest solution.
I would do this in JavaScript :

```
var t = str.split(':');
var result = '<Entry Name="'+t[1]+'" Code="'+t[0].trim().replace(/ /g,'')+'"/>';
```